# Remove the view and layout name from SEF URL in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, joomla2.5, sef, joomla-sef-urls

I am using joomla 2.5 I want to display the SEF without the view and layout name.

```
http://localhost/cars/vehicles/buyer/vehicle_overview/7/18
to 
http://localhost/cars/vehicles/carname
```

In that above url I have to display the name of car instead of view,layout and ids. I am using the js_autoz component and want to change the SEF in that component.

Could you provide any examples to remove the view and layout? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have to create one router.php file inside the component frontend (Site).

Demo Link :

http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component 
[setting joomla component router.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926445/setting-joomla-component-router-php)